# Determine if function is Riemann integrable on interval

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I am supposed to determine if function given by:

$$\varphi \left ( x \right )=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\ 1 , \left ( \exists m,n\in\mathbb{N} \right )x=\frac{m}{2^{n}}\\ 
\\0, else
\end{matrix}\right.$$

is Riemann integrable on interval $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$.

What I did so far:

I found out partition, $P_{n}=\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )$, and I know that to any $\varepsilon > 0$ we choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so that $\frac{1}{n}< \frac{\epsilon }{2}$. Then $U\left ( Pn,\varphi  \right )=\frac{1}{n}\varphi \left ( t_{i} \right )$, where  $t_{i}=\frac{m}{2^{n}}$,

but I do not know how to continue, or what I have to do with the second part of the function.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower sums $L(\phi,P)$ are clearly zero.

Also note that the set $\{\frac{m}{2^n}:m\in \Bbb{Z},n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ is dense on the reals and thus on $[0,1]$(and on $[0,1]$ you need only that $m \in \Bbb{N}$)

So if you take a partition $P$ you will always have $U(\phi,P) \geq 1$ because the supremum of the function on each subinterval will be $1$.

Thus $U(\phi,P)-L(\phi,P) \geq 1$ so the function cannot be Riemman integrable on $[0,1]$

Comment: Lower sums are clearly zero because we take the left points of the subintervals? and why is supremum of the function on each interval 1? Can you please explain it?

Comment: @Shelley...by density of the sets we will have that $\sup\phi(x)=1$ in every subinterval of the partition..so the sum will be 1,because then we only sum the lengths of the intervlas ,(which sums to the length of $[0,1]$...the lower sum will be zero since $\inf f(x)=0$ on every subinterval of the partition...this exercise is very similar to why the Dirichlet function is not riemman integrable and the proof is the same..

Comment: And we do not do anything with the second part which says that it is zero for something else?  And it is not Riemann integrable because it is unbounded on interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Shelley For the lower sum, you take the smallest function value in the sub-interval (or the infimum if there is no smallest value). Similiarly, you take the highest function value (or supremum) in the subinterval for the upper sum. The minimum function value in each subinterval will always be $0$, as for example all irrational numbers have function value $0$, and each subinterval contains irrational numbers. The maximum function value in each subinterval will always be $1$, because each subinterval will always contain a number of the form $\frac m{2^n}$, that's what the dense argument is for.

Comment: @Shelley.. No..it is not riemman integrable,by the Riemman criterion  of integrability...yes we do not need that,..we only need that to prove that the lower sums are zero

Comment: @Shelley: Why do you think a function that can only take values $0$ and $1$ can be unbounded?

Comment: @Ingix I thought it, because I misunderstood one part, but now I get it.. thanks for explanation

Comment: @MariosGretsas Thank you so much, it is clear to me now

Answer (score 0):

For a somewhat different approach, if $p\in [0,1]$ is irrational, then the density of the rationals in $[0,1]$ implies that $f$ is not continuous at $p.$ And since the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ have positive measure, $f$ is not Riemann integrable.